# ClassCastException getOrDefault for return value Object

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I have a map of the type `ConcurrentMap<String, Object>` for which I want to use `getOrDefault`.
Now the returned value is type casted into `BigDecimal` if key exists.
When I am using the below code, I get class cast exception.

```
final BigDecimal value= (BigDecimal) map.getOrDefault("key", 0);
```

I tried using (Object)0 but it makes no sense given everything in Java is an object. If `getOrDefault` returns Object, then why is it throwing exception on casting 0 as Bigdecimal?
I used the below and it worked

```
final BigDecimal value= (BigDecimal) map.getOrDefault("key", BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

What's the reason that 0 cannot be casted?

Comment: `0` is not a BigDecimal and cannot be cast to it. It can be cast to `Integer`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645488/java-lang-integer-cannot-be-cast-to-java-math-biginteger)  [explanation of ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/explanation-of-classcastexception-in-java)

Comment: @Eran Technically that would be boxing, not casting.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast 0 (or any `Integer`) to `BigDecimal`. If you want to convert them, use `BigInteger.valueOf(0)`

You can use `BigDecimal.ZERO` instead in your code for that specific constant.

Comment: It's, however, weird, why we can't cast an `int` to BigDecimal.

Comment: Not weird, that's because `Ìnteger` and `BigDecimal` do not extend each other. You can only case `A` to `B` if `B extends A`. You have to use the `BigInteger.valueOf` method to convert (not cast) them..